# Generating a header and a set of given sentences with Excel / VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Just to note, I have never used Excel in such an advanced way before (in fact, I have never used any of the functions before... but I'm currently searching for tutorials on Excel online and VBA, and I'm asking here just in case anyone knows better which to use, and how to use them effectively).

I'm giving Excel **5 headers** in **column A** (which are also sentences) and **10 sentences**  in **column B** to generate **3 paragraphs** randomly, each using **1 header and 3 sentences each**.

How do I go about achieving that? I know Excel has a RAND() function, but that seems to only apply to numbers...

More to come, I'll update if I actually find the solution as well.

Comment: can the headers and sentences repeat in the three paragraphs? as in header 1 to appear in all three paragraphs?

Comment: yup, they can. for example the generated statements can be A1 + B3/B5/B10, next can be A2 + B2/B7/B5, last could be A1 + B1/B10/B3. Doesn't have to be in order, just randomly generated.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you guys included screenshots -- if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data was in `A1:A5` and `B1:B10` of the first sheet then something like this using `RANDBETWEEN`

```
  Sub GetText()
Dim A
Dim B
A = Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).[a1], Sheets(1).[a5])
B = Sheets(1).Range(Sheets(1).[b1], Sheets(1).[b10])
MsgBox A(Application.RandBetween(1, UBound(A)), 1) & " " & B(Application.RandBetween(1, UBound(B)), 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, but where does the output go?

Comment: er, both. where does the code go, and where does it display? like, all in column C or something like that.

Comment: I found the VBA editor, and now I see you've made it use MsgBox. Can I output the macro into a column, like starting from C1 to C5 instead of having a popup box?

Comment: After searching around, I found that using a `Function` instead of `Sub` actually allows me to return a value in the box itself.

Comment: Anyway, kudos to you for helping me out. My final answer was to change `Sub` to `Function`, and return it on the Excel sheet.

Comment: just another question -- if I wanted Dim A values to only be used once, how do I go about doing it?

Answer (score 0):

in cell C1 put:

```
=RANDBETWEEN(1;5)

in cell D1 put:
=RANDBETWEEN(1;10)
```

in cell E1 put:

```
=IF(D1=1;RANDBETWEEN(2;10);IF(D1=10;RANDBETWEEN(1;9);CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1;2);RANDBETWEEN(1;D1-1);RANDBETWEEN(D1+1;10))))
```

in cell F1 put:

```
=IF(MAX(D1:E1)-MIN(D1:E1)=1;IF(MIN(D1:E1)=1;RANDBETWEEN(3;10);IF(MIN(D1:E1)=9;RANDBETWEEN(1;8);CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1;2);RANDBETWEEN(1;MIN(D1:E1)-1);RANDBETWEEN(MAX(D1:E1)+1;10))));IF(MAX(D1:E1)-MIN(D1:E1)=9;RANDBETWEEN(2;9);IF(MIN(D1:E1)=1;CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1;2);RANDBETWEEN(2;MAX(D1:E1)-1);RANDBETWEEN(MAX(D1:E1)+1;10));IF(MAX(D1:E1)=10;CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1;2);RANDBETWEEN(1;MIN(D1:E1)-1);RANDBETWEEN(MIN(D1:E1)+1;9));CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1;3);RANDBETWEEN(1;MIN(D1:E1)-1);RANDBETWEEN(MIN(D1:E1)+1;MAX(D1:E1)-1);RANDBETWEEN(MAX(D1:E1)+1;10))))))
```

in cell G1 put:

```
=CONCATENATE(INDIRECT("A" & C1);" "; INDIRECT("B" & D1); " ";INDIRECT("B" & E1);" ";INDIRECT("B" & F1))
```

copy down cells C1:G1 and hide columns C:F

Comment: Did you mean ':' instead of ';'?

Comment: doesn't work?!?!   perhaps **,** instead of **;** depending on system language.

Comment: Um... I feel like an idiot, how do you even get it to calculate? I'm clicking calculate sheet and nothing is happening.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010 btw.

Comment: what do you want to calculate? if your formula appears in the cells, instead of the calculated result, then right click the cell, go to format cells, and in Number tab, set format to General. then OK then press F2 on the cell and then ENTER.....