# Loop through Column A in Excel VBA, get a random word from Column B and output the row in Column C

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-2010, vba

I'm very new to VBA Macros and Excel, and I have a small problem that I need to solve.

Say I have a **Column A** that has 20 rows of a single word/letter, and a **Column B** that has 5 rows of a single word/letter.

How do I loop through **Column A**, starting from A1 and randomly select a row in **Column B** to add together to form a new string which will be output in **Column C**?

Meaning I want the output to look like this in **Column C**:

```
A1 (for each A) + B2 (random)
A2 (for each A) + B4 (random)
A3 (for each A) + B1 (random)
A4 (for each A) + B3 (random)
A5 (for each A) + B4 (random)
A6 (for each A) + B2 (random)
...
```

and so on and so forth.

Anyone has any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Generating a header and a set of given sentences with Excel / VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17801780/generating-a-header-and-a-set-of-given-sentences-with-excel-vba)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
Sub HTH()
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim iRandom As Integer

    For Each rCell In Range("A1:A20")
        iRandom = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(1, 5)
        rCell.Offset(, 2).Value = CStr(rCell.Value & Cells(iRandom, "B").Value)
    Next rCell

End Sub
```

As you have tagged Excel 2007 you may need to use this instead:

```
iRandom = Round((5 - 1) * Rnd + 1, 0)
```